# Access Error: Syntax Error - When placing DCount in an IF statement

Tags: vba, if-statement

This feature I am trying to create has multiple functions. I want it to make sure that the text box is not blank, then I want it to check if the application exists and if it does load the application.

I can only get it to work if I remove the inital check on the text box being blank. I got it to work but when I restarted the database it stopped working. I keep receiving the following error message:

> Run-time error '3075'
>
> > Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression '[AppID]=   '.

This is the code I am using:

```
Private Sub cmd_loadapp_click()
    If Me.txtAppID = "" Then
      MsgBox "Application ID cannot be blank, please try again.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid ID"
    Else
      If DCount("[AppID]", "tblApp", "[AppID] = " & Me![txtAppID] & "  ") > 0 Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", acNormal, , "[AppID]=" & Me.txtAppID
        Me.txtAppID = ""
    Else
      MsgBox "Application ID does not exist, please try again.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid ID"
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help anyone can give me would be greatly appreicated.

Best Wishes
Sampson

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on, the if statement or openform?

Comment: Hi Gareth

I am receiving the error on the following line:

             If DCount("[AppID]", "tblApp", "[AppID] = " & Me![txtAppID] & "  ") > 0 Then

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone whp contributed to answering this question. I have now fixed this problem and another error which came about due to my use of **txtAppID = ""** at the start of the code. This is what I used to get it working.

```
If IsNull(txtAppID) Then
    MsgBox "Application ID cannot be blank, please try again.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid ID "
Else
If DCount("[AppID]", "tblApp", "[AppID] = " & Val(txtAppID)) = 1 Then
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", acNormal, , "[AppID]=" & Me.txtAppID
    Me.txtAppID = ""
    Else
    MsgBox "Application ID does not exist, please try again.", vbOKOnly, "Invalid ID"
    End If
    End If
```

It was a long struggle but we got there! Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

In your DCount function, if you appending the contents of the txtAppID control from the form, I think you should replace Me![txtAppID] with Me.txtAppID

Comment: Hi ChipsLetten

I have made the adjustment which you suggested and I am still recieving the same error. Thank you for your help so far.